# new with delegates and lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

Basically I want to create a method that can return a string message regarding on what currently happening inside a method
example:

```
public MainMethod()
{
  //Execute One
  //Execute Two
  //Execute Three
}
```

upon using it I'm thinking of like this

```
something = delegate (string message) {console.writeline("{0}",message)};
```

the output would be

```
Execute One
Execute Two
Execute Three
```

Is this possible using delegate or lambda? if yes can I ask for an example on how I should correctly implement this? if no please help me with alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Func` and `Action`.  They make interacting with delegates much easier.  `Func`s have return values, `Action`s do not:

```
 public MainMethod()
 {
    Action<string> writerAction = (message) => Console.WriteLine(message); 

    writerAction("Execute One");
    writerAction("Execute Two");
    writerAction("Execute Three");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need